# how should I do for this makefile?

Tags: makefile

```
$cat makefile

 AA:=3

.PHONY:all
all:test1.o test2.o
    @echo all AA=${AA}
    @gcc test1.o test2.o -o test

test1.o:test1.c
    @echo 1 AA=${AA}
    @gcc -c test1.c -o test1.o

AA:=2
test2.o:test2.c
    @echo 2 AA=${AA}
    @gcc -c test2.c -o test2.o

.PHONY:clean
clean:
    rm -f *.o
    rm -f *~
```

the output of this makefile is:

```
1 AA=2
2 AA=2
all AA=2
```

but I want the output like this:

```
1 AA=3
2 AA=2
all AA=3
```

I tried some methods but all failed.
how should I do? thank you

Comment: i think you got the whole concept in the wrong way
a makefile doesn't necessarily execute in the same order the "conditions" where made it also depends on the last modification date of the dependencies and basically all the rules you have 
so here is a tutorial that i hope should help : 
http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Simple-Makefile.html#Simple-Makefile

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [target-specific](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Target_002dspecific) variables:

```
all: AA:=3
all:test1.o test2.o
    @echo all AA=${AA}
    @gcc test1.o test2.o -o test

test2.o: AA:=2
test2.o:test2.c
    @echo 2 AA=${AA}
    @gcc -c test2.c -o test2.o
```